# No route matches [POST] "/links/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I have a model called 'links.' In routes.rb I have defined it with:

```
resources :links
```

I have a form in /links/new it looks like this:

```
    <%= form_for :links do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :url %>
      <%= f.url_field :url, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit :"Create Link", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

When I submit it, I get the error `No route matches [POST] "/links/new"`
even though this is in the list of routes:

```
new_link_path   GET /links/new(.:format)    links#new
```

What is the problem?

Comment: As per Rails naming convention, model name should be singular i.e `Link`

Comment: @dkp That is the name of model, sorry I mis-typed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <%= form_for(Link.new) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :url %>
  <%= f.url_field :url, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.submit "Create Link", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

add NEW route method in controller Controller

```
def new
    @link = Link.new
  end
```

When you will visit to links/new then new route method will call and render links/new template. so add below code in tamplete

```
 <% form_for(:link, @link, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :title %>
       <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :url %>
      <%= f.url_field :url, class: "form-control" %>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :description %>
     <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.submit "Create Link", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and handle create request in create action of link controller

```
def create
    @link = Link.new params[:link]
    if @link.save
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @link.id
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

dont forget to allow params for link in controller.
this is a proper way to create a new record in ror